# How do I suppress the following commands from throwing errors on a pre-build event?

Tags: c#, command-line, build, command, prebuild

I have tried piping the following two calls to NUL with no luck:

```
net stop "Logging Service">nul 2>&1
taskkill /IM LogServiceHost.exe /f >nul 2>&1
```

They will stop my build cycle from going through:

```
Error   1   The command "
net stop "Logging Service">nul 2>&1
taskkill /IM LogServiceHost.exe /f >nul 2>&1" exited with code 128. LoggingUtilities
```

Any ideas how I can just fire these prebuild events and not care what they return, and not have it ever suppress my build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line at the end of your post-build event. This should cause the automatically-generated .bat script to return an ERRORLEVEL 0.

```
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Problem with this is that I may have errors from commands I include above these two that I still want it to prevent building in case they occur. What would I do in that case?

Comment: Learn batch scripting. :) After every line at which you want to stop the post-build if an error occurs, you need to check ERRORLEVEL. Something like `if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1` would do.